# tmux - use detach from session listing

Tags: session, tmux

Anyone know how to do this? You hit magic key+s to get the list of sessions, but if you choose to attach to one there it uses `attach` rather than `attach -d`.

I really dislike when my terminal is smaller because of the original terminal the session is in, and I do not mind re-attaching on the original system once I get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> is (by default) bound to the command `choose-tree` which presents the list of sessions and then runs `switch-client -t <choosen-session>`. If you want it to run `attach -dt <choose-session>` instead, then you can rebind it like this:

```
bind-key s choose-tree -b "attach-session -dt '%%'"
```

Comment: This has stopped working I believe since 2.0; definitely not working in 2.1 unfortunately. Not sure yet how to fix.